# UIBezierPath and curve to point but only with one CGPoint instead of two

Tags: ios, swift, cgpoint

This is my code :

```
private func bezierPathForSmile(fractionOfMaxSmile : Double) -> UIBezierPath
    {
        let mouthWidth = faceRadius / Scaling.FaceRadiusToMouthWidthRatio
        let mouthHeight = faceRadius / Scaling.FaceRadiusToMouthHeightRatio
        let mouthVerticalOffset = faceRadius / Scaling.FaceRadiusToMouthOffsetRatio

        let smileHeight = CGFloat(max(min(fractionOfMaxSmile, 1), -1)) * mouthHeight    //an einai pio megalo tou 1 krata to 1 an einai pio megalo apo -1 krata to pio megalo

        let start = CGPoint(x: faceCenter.x - mouthWidth / 2, y: faceCenter.y + mouthVerticalOffset)
        let end = CGPoint(x: start.x + mouthWidth, y: start.y)
        let cp1 = CGPoint(x: start.x + mouthWidth / 3, y: start.y + smileHeight)
        let cp2 = CGPoint(x: end.x - mouthWidth / 3, y: cp1.y)

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.moveToPoint(start)
        path.addCurveToPoint(end, controlPoint1: cp1, controlPoint2: cp2)
        path.lineWidth = lineWidth
        return path
    }
```

i would like to ask if there is a way to get "curve" between a start CGPoint and an end CGPoint by only specifying the CGPoint of the (start.x + end.x)/2 and the deviation of it's y axis from the start.y or the end.y instead of using:

```
path.addCurveToPoint(end, controlPoint1: cp1, controlPoint2: cp2)
```

that has two control points. in other words i want to make the exact thing above happen by only specifying the GCPoint of the center.(start + end)/2
thanks.

Comment: it actually works that way(and why should it?) but i am looking a way for having to input once the CGPoint parameter instead of inputing it twice..
thanks for you answer

Comment: `addQuadCurveToPoint`

Comment: You sir are completely correct!Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `addCurveToPoint` uses two control points, whereas `addQuadCurveToPoint` only takes one control point.

[image]

Image from the [Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH11-SW23).